# AWS Custom Verification Email Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am working on AWS Cognito and below are two questions for Message Customizations.

1) I am working on AWS Cognito for "email verification messages" using "Link"
Verification type. I am getting an issue with "Email message" to make it dynamic.

2) How to send different "Email message" content based on user group or conditionally?

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: There is a cognito trigger, "Custom message" which is invoked before a verification or MFA message is sent, allowing you to customize the message dynamically. You can create a lambda function to create content based on the user group or whatever conditon you have.

Comment: Thanks for reply,
I have tried this but not worked for me let me know if I am missed out anything. Below are the steps.
1) I am using amplifyService to singUp in Cognito.
2) I am using Nodejs and I have created lambda function with "CustomMessage_SignUp" as event.triggerSource with reference given 
here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html (Custom Message for Sign Up Example )
3) Set created lambda function Triggers in "Custom message".
But it doesn't worked for me.

Comment: is the trigger ever called? is cognito sending a default msg instead?

Comment: No trigger isn't called it's sending default Email Message from "Email message" section of Cognito.

Comment: Yes trigger is working but it's sending default Email Message from "Email message" section of Cognito.

Comment: it looks like an  issue with your custom msg, {##link##} is not configured correctly

Comment: Please check this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html  It only mentions confirmation code for all the cases. I guess they might have stopped supporting custom link. Please check if the code works or not

Comment: Correct I have replaced "codeParameter" with "linkParameter" and it works for me but receving plain text in email content.
Just want to know we need to use SES to send HTML content / Formatted email?
Please let me know how to do this.
Thanks

Comment: Yes the HTML tags works as well. Just replace you plain text with a your HTML content. mAke sure your linkParameter is properly added in the content. It will work.

Comment: Also you need to authorize cognito to send emails using ses. Check this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pool-settings-ses-authorization-to-send-email.html

Comment: @SomnathRokade "Yes trigger is working but it's sending default Email Message from "Email message" section of Cognito."
Same issue here. Any solution?

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me. So if someone knows a better answer please point me. Sending a link selecting the "link" option didn't work for me.
So I tried adding the link manually in the body selecting the "code" option. But that didn't work at the start either as @SomnathRokade and @snehanshu.js suggested.

This is my lambda function.

```js
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
var welcomeMessage = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Dear ${event.userName},</p>

<p>Anything</p>

<p>Any text before the link <a href="http://localhost:3000/changePassword?username=${event.userName}">here.</a> Your username is your Network Rail email address. Your temporary password is ${event.request.codeParameter}.</p>

<p>Any text</p>

<p>Any other text</p>

<p>Many Thanks </p>
</body>
</html>
`;

if (event.triggerSource === "CustomMessage_AdminCreateUser") {
event.response.emailSubject = "CAT Welcome Email";
event.response.emailMessage = welcomeMessage;
}
return context.done(null,event);
};
```

This DID NOT work.

I googled and found different places referring to "event.request.userName", "event.request.userAttributes.sub" etc instead of "event.userName". But they didn't work either.

Then I tried printing the event object in lambda console logs. I found the value for all of the above fields were same. Interestingly there was no "event.request.userName" field in the object. Instead there was "event.request.usernameParameter". Still, the value was the same as "event.userName". Anyway, I tried adding "event.request.usernameParameter" and surprisingly it worked.

After all, I found [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html#node.js) explaining it.

So the bottom line is use "Code" option with having "event.request.usernameParameter" and "event.request.codeParameter" in the email body. It worked.

Hope I helped somebody.